# Assign to variable inside one line if-else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I want to assign to global variable in a one line `if-else` statement

The statement in one line:

```
wins += 1 if num > num2 else lose += 1;
```

I get invalid syntax error, with one line.

The original statement is working:

```
if num > num2:
    wins += 1
else:
    lose += 1
```

I'm using more than 5000 statements, each one line and separate with semicolon `;` to make it all one line.

Comment: @rdas Yes i meant += 1. Fixed

Comment: FWIW the 4-line version is much better than trying to fit it into one line

Comment: You're using _5,000_ statements? Why not use e.g. a dictionary?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes im not expert with python , i can simplify the 5000 statements by doing one and calcualte the others from 1 statement, but i havent thought to use dicts for this purpose

Comment: @rdas Im using many variables and many conditions and each condition is calcualting a percentage, if i do it in basic 4 line statement i have more than 20000 lines

Comment: 20,000 simple lines of code is still better than 5000 hard to read lines of code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assignments are statements, not expressions, and as such they cannot be part of a conditional *expression*. You can do it in one line, though, even if that is not an end in itself:

```
wins, lose = wins + (num > num2), lose + (num <= num2)
```

or with an assignment expression:

```
wins, lose = wins + (w := num > num2), lose + (not w)
```

Answer (score 3):

You **can** do it in one line as assignment expressions with the walrus (`:=`) operator (Python 3.8+):

```
(wins := wins + 1) if num > num2 else (lose := lose + 1)
```

but it doesn't make much sense to. You're modifying two different objects, and trying to cram both into one statement isn't especially logical.

The 4-line version is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Im using many variables and many conditions and each condition is calcualting a percentage, if i do it in basic 4 line statement i have more than 20000 lines

Comment: I would suggest then that a much better optimization is to change how to process a lot of data without 5000 blocks of code, so that using 1 line of code vs 4 lines of code per item isn't so important.

Comment: Of course, i can optimize my code, With this many conditions the processing speed also so much slower